# Mouse pointer/cursor disappears or doesn't show properly

Tags: mouse, lubuntu, cursor

I recently installed the new Lubuntu 12.10 but I'm having problems with mouse pointer image. When I start the OS everything works fine, but if I open some programs (for example Chromium) my cursor starts disappearing on clickable elements/icons/menus and come back only if I move it around. I tried to change cursor theme from white to black: the result is that it remains white in standby conditions or when hovering windows borders (even after rebooting, in order to loading the new theme). 
The problem exists with guest account too. I had no problem with 12.04, and already tested both an upgrade and a fresh installation of the OS.

UPDATE: I have many reasons to think that the problem is caused by lack of compatible drivers in latest version of Lubuntu. I recently installed LXLE, a Linux distro based on Lubuntu 12.04, and the problem seems to be disappeared (I'll continue to test). I am a newbie of Linux world and don't know if this can help, but I wanted to share it with you.

Comment: I started having this same problem on Lubuntu 12.10, after it had been running with no problems on my Thinkpad t43p for a while. Not sure if this is due to some "upgrade" or to a hardware failure.
BTW-- Lubuntu is based on LXDE, and not the other way around.